# Pointer and Integer issues in C

Tags: c, pointers, integer, return

Function is waiting for a pointer but I want to return an integer in the function lookup (i can't modify the return type of the function), what can i do to solve this problem ?

```
int hashtable_insert(HashTable ** ptable, void *data, void (*delete) (void *))
    {
        if(hashtable_lookup(*ptable, data) != -1){
            return -1;
            }
    
     data = malloc(sizeof(size_t));
     list_append((*ptable)->list, data, (*ptable)->size);
     _hashtable_resize(ptable);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

warning: comparison between pointer and integer
if(hashtable_lookup(*ptable, data) != -1){

```
void * hashtable_lookup(HashTable * table, void *data)
{
for(int i = 0; i < (table)->length; i++){
    if((table)->list[i] == data){
            return data;
        }
    }
return -1;
}
```

warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
return -1;

Answer (score 2):

> Function is waiting for a pointer but I want to return an integer in the function lookup (i can't modify the return type of the function), what can i do to solve this problem ?

If the function returns `void *` and you cannot change that, then returning an integer simply is not an option.  You could return an integer *converted to* a pointer (and compare the return value against a similar value), but unless your hash table supports null values, a null pointer would make a better failure code:

```
void * hashtable_lookup(HashTable * table, void *data) {
    // look up data ...

    // lookup failed
    return NULL;
}

// ...

        if (hashtable_lookup(*ptable, data) != NULL) {
            // data is already present in the hash table
            return -1;
        }
```

But if a null pointer would be valid data for the table, then

```
void * hashtable_lookup(HashTable * table, void *data) {
    // look up data ...

    // lookup failed
    return (void *) -1;
}

// ...

        if (hashtable_lookup(*ptable, data) != (void *) -1) {
            // data is already present in the hash table
            return -1;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First warning is because you are comparing a `void*` to an `int`. The second one is because you're returning an `int` instead of a pointer.

You could add casts here and there to remove the warnings (`if(hashtable_lookup(*ptable, data) != (void*)(-1)){` and `return (void*)(-1);`, but it would be harder to read and more error-prone since you usually check pointers to not be NULL, but not to be different than "-1".

Typically, you would return a NULL pointer to indicate that the function failed. Also, you might have `if(hashtable_lookup(*ptable, data) != -1){` wrong since it looks like when hasthable_lookup() returns -1 it failed.

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
int hashtable_insert(HashTable ** ptable, void *data, void (*delete) (void *))
{
    if(hashtable_lookup(*ptable, data) == NULL){
        return -1;
    }

    data = malloc(sizeof(size_t));
    list_append((*ptable)->list, data, (*ptable)->size);
    _hashtable_resize(ptable);

    return 0;
}

void * hashtable_lookup(HashTable * table, void *data)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < (table)->length; i++){
        if((table)->list[i] == data){
            return data;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```